# how to display all elements of an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I wish to print elements of the array below

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

However, only 3 digits must be printed at a time, e.g,

step 1: should print 1,2,3

step 2: should print 2,3,4

step 3: should print 3,4,5

step 4: should print 1,2,3

step 5: should print 2,3,4

and the loop continues .....

I wish to display the thumbnails of this slider in a manner that they will fit a small screen.

http://www.tympanus.net/Tutorials/FullscreenSlideshowAudio

That means only a few thumbnails must appear at a time, while the rest are invisible for a short while.

Thanks..

Comment: Can you at least show what you have attempted?

Comment: *"step 4: should print 1,2,3"* - Why? Also, does the loop have an end?

Comment: What part of this are you having trouble with?

Comment: How long the loop should be continued?

Comment: and when the loop ends?

Comment: What is the reason behind doing this? Please explain

Comment: I wish to display the thumbnails of this slider in a manner that they will fit a small screen. http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FullscreenSlideshowAudio/ That means only a few thumbnails must appear at a time, while the rest are invisible for a short while.

Comment: @SolidBusiness: That's not really a loop… At least not a synchronous one. You just need to get 3 items from your array every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you wanted to display `3` elements from the array each time and when the last element is displayed you want to repeat the process again you are suppose to use `setInterval()` to call the function after a specified time continuously and reset the index to 0 immediately after the last element is displayed. Else increment the initial or counter value. Try this way,

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];
var initVal = 0;

setInterval(function(){
    console.log(array[initVal] + "," + array[initVal+1] + "," + array[initVal+2]);
    initVal = initVal == 2 ? 0 : initVal+1;
}, 500);
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/eemu9jre/)